# why would one loop work but a virtually identical loop not print data to a file?

Tags: c, openssl, md5sum

This code isn't printing anything to hashfile2.txt but does print to hashfile1.txt and i'm completely confused as to why. If I move the loop that controls hashfile2.txt to before hashfile1.txt it also doesn't work. Unless i'm completely missing something they are both the exact same loops with different variables of the same type.

```
void readfiles()
{
    FILE *file1 = fopen ("plaintext1.txt", "r");
    FILE *file2 = fopen ("plaintext2.txt", "r");
    char results[] = "results.txt";
    FILE *resultfile = fopen(results, "w");
    FILE *hash1 = fopen("hashfile1.txt", "w");
    FILE *hash2 = fopen("hashfile2.txt", "w");
    char hash1line[128];
    char hash2line[128];
    char plaintext1line[128];
    char plaintext2line[128];
    unsigned char sha256_digest[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    unsigned char md5_digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    unsigned char newline[] = {" "};

    if(file1 != NULL && file2 != NULL)
    {
        while (1)
            {
                if (fgets(plaintext1line, sizeof plaintext1line, file1)!= NULL && fgets(plaintext2line,
             sizeof plaintext2line, file2)!= NULL)
                {
                        location.file1read = (unsigned char *)plaintext1line;
                        location.file2read = (unsigned char *)plaintext2line;
                        if (location.algorithm == 0)
                        {
                            MD5(location.file1read, sizeof location.file1read, md5_digest);

                            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof md5_digest; i++)
                            {
                                fprintf(hash1, "%x", md5_digest[i]);
                            }
                            fprintf(hash1, "%s\n", newline);

                            MD5(location.file2read, sizeof location.file2read, md5_digest);

                            for (int j = 0; j < sizeof md5_digest; j++)
                            {
                                fprintf(hash2, "%x", md5_digest[j]);
                            }
                            fprintf(hash2, "%s\n", newline);
                        }

                        else if (location.algorithm == 1)
                        {
                            SHA256(location.file1read, sizeof location.file1read, sha256_digest);
                            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof location.file1read; i++)
                            {
                                fprintf(hash1, "%x", sha256_digest[i]);
                            }
                            fprintf(hash1, "%s\n", newline);
                            SHA256(location.file2read, sizeof location.file2read, sha256_digest);

                            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof location.file2read; i++)
                            {
                                fprintf(hash2, "%x", sha256_digest[i]);
                            }
                            fprintf(hash2, "%s\n", newline);
                        }

                    for(int i = 0; fgets(hash1line, sizeof hash1line, hash1) !=NULL; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; fgets(hash2line, sizeof hash2line, hash2) !=NULL; j++)
                        {
                            if(strcmp(hash1line, hash2line) == 0)
                            {
                                fprintf(resultfile, "collision found on line %d of %s %s\ncollision found on %d of %s %s\n", 
                                i, location.hashfile1, hash1line, j, location.hashfile2, hash2line);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            else 
            {
                   break;
            }
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should move the final nested loop, where you check for collisions out of the main loop `while (1)`. In that loop, you access both hash files in reading mode when they were opened in write mode. You can compare the hashes that way, but you must close the files and re-open them in ´"r"` mode and you must `rewind` the inner file in the outer loop. A more efficient way will be to read the data to arrays, sort the two arrays and then walk these arrays simultaneously, always comparing the entries at the current positions.

Comment: I did have to rewind the final loop that compares the hashes. The issue with it writing to the hashfile2.txt was because I wasn't closing the file. I think the buffer was getting stuck and didn't save the data to the file before ending the loop.

Comment: File output is commonly buffered and will only be written to disk now and then. You can force the writing by flushing the file, or when you close the file what includes the flushing.